# How to find last element in Array list using jsonpath expression?

Tags: jsonpath

I have json string like below

```
[
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 0
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 1
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 2
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 3
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 4
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 5
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 6
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "Hi Test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 7
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "Hi Test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 8
    },
    {
        "topic": "inputTopic",
        "key": "0",
        "message": "Hi Test",
        "partition": 0,
        "offset": 9
    }
]
```

How can I get last item using jsonpath expression?

```
 {
    "topic": "inputTopic",
    "key": "0",
    "message": "Hi Test",
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 9
}
```

Comment: We can get first element by using expression like this  " $.[1] " .

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share your findings / code.

Answer (score 34):

As you can read in the [docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) you can ether do a

```
$..book[(@.length-1)]
```

as mentioned by Duncan above. Or you can

```
$..book[-1:]
```

Personally I find the first a bit more expressive, the latter a bit smarter to write. The latter also seems to be the intended default. I'd say it's a question of personal flavor.

Comment: Even more convenient is "$..book[-1]" which returns just the last element, whereas "$..book[-1:]" returns an array containing the last element.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the underlying language features when using JsonPath, so in JavaScript for example, the length property is available.  You can therefore say I want the last one by asking for length minus one.

Assuming you are using JsonPath from JavaScript the following query will find the last item:

```
$.[(@.length-1)]
```

You can see the query working here on this online JsonPath tester: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/sample/jsonpathlastinarray

Answer (score 3):

What was working here for me was:

```
$..[-1:]
```

[image]

You can test it here: https://jsonpath.com/